# celery workers + postgres CPU usage bouncing

Tags: django, postgresql, redis, celery, django-celery

I am running a Django project with Celery workers on a Redis server. Some tasks are responsible for streaming tweets from Twitter API, some others process the tweets.

The thing that worries me, is that I get a bouncing CPU load with these processes constantly "coming alive" and "going asleep" along with the corresponding PostgreSQL processes which write the tweets to the db.

Here is how it looks like on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine with and SDD.
[image]

Why do I get this weird unbalanced in time load? Is it fixable with Celery/Redis/OS parameters or it's something in my code? I don't have any process in the code with that periodicity and when I stream tweets I do it for several mins constantly.

This behavior results in an annoying lag even when typing.

Comment: 1) Check the process list (top) 2) check the transaction list (pgadmin) 3) check the locklist (pgadmin) 4) Check the postgres logfile.

Comment: thanks for the tip @joop!

Comment: I was checking the `pid`s in the `celery flower` tasks and checking which of those processes behaves how in `htop`.

Though I didn't know about pgAdmin's "Server Status" tool with all the locks etc. I also had not enabled the postgres logging, so will do that and will try make more sense of the situation. Will post an update with more details.

Comment: The point is: there are multiple scenarios that lead to this observed behaviour. (the simplest one is: too many competing clients, fighting for locks) (another one could be: stalled by autovacuum) A third additional one: lack of indexes and/or bad tuning. (try to fetch some generated query plans) BTW: do your insert client do row-at-a-time / commit-at-a-time processing?

Comment: I am not sure about row-at-a-time and commit-at-a-time... can you elaborate on those terms a bit?
I basically get a stream of tweets, iterate over them and save them one-by-one into the db. Later I process them in batches assigning the tweets to the occurring hashtags in a separate hashtag table.

Comment: As you have mentioned I do have Redis locks and I also have slightly aggressive autovacuum on the tweet table and the hashtag table (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/aggressive-autovacuum-on-postgresql) because of the issue of crazy fast growing hashtag TOAST table which grows because I probably have too many updates into this small table.

Comment: Can't tell from here [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem ] Many updates in separate transactions ?